# Filtering data is not working in firestore android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an application where I have filtered my data from firestore but it is not working please guide me on where I am mistaking the code. it is neither showing any error or exception i have no idea where it is going wrong??

**code for the filtering data in my recyclerview**

```
 @Override
public Filter getFilter() {

    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence keyword) {

            ArrayList<RecyclerviewModel> filteredData = new ArrayList<>();

            if (keyword.toString().isEmpty())
            {

                filteredData.addAll(backup);

            }else {

                firebaseFirestore.collection("users").whereEqualTo("search", keyword.toString().toLowerCase()).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots)
                    {

                        datalist.clear();
                        if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                            for (RecyclerviewModel obj : backup) {
                                if (obj.getName().toString().toLowerCase().contains(keyword.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                                    filteredData.add(obj);
                                }
                            }
                        }else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(context, "data not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                        }

                    }

                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                        Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

            }
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredData;
            results.count = filteredData.size();
            return  results;

        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {

            datalist.clear();
            datalist.addAll((ArrayList<RecyclerviewModel>)filterResults.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    return filter;
}
```

**CODE FOR THE SEARCHVIEW IN MAINACTIVITY**

```
 searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            recyclerviewAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

            return false;
        }
    });
```

**THE ERROR IT IS THROWING**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:588) at com.example.sharedviewmodelapp.RecyclerviewAdapter$2.publishResults(RecyclerviewAdapter.java:239)
```

**IT IS THWRING ERROR ON THE publishResults method line**

```
                datalist.addAll((ArrayList<RecyclerviewModel>)filterResults.values);
```

CODE FOR RECYCLLRVIEW ADAPTER

```
ArrayList<RecyclerviewModel> datalist;
ArrayList<RecyclerviewModel> backup;
Context context;
 public RecyclerviewAdapter(ArrayList<RecyclerviewModel> datalist, Context context, HomeFragment homeFragment) {
    this.datalist = datalist;
    this.context = context;
    this.homeFragment = homeFragment;
    backup = new ArrayList<>(datalist);
}
```

Comment: If you want to local search recycle item then just filter the available list in recycle view and refresh the list.

Comment: @AdityaNandardhane brother i am filter the data from firestore but this code is not working when i enter something inside searchview it does not show anything

Comment: Since you're using Java, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444) will really help. If want at some point in time try programming in Kotlin, this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-in-real-time-using-jetpack-compose-952abaab15c5) will also help.

Comment: @AlexMamo sir I am using the same filter approach but the problem is why this code is not working for me

Comment: Sorry sir but i am facing difficulty understanding your suggested documents.

Comment: "is not working" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors?

Comment: Please add that information to your question and indicate the exact line of code at which the error occurs.

Comment: @AlexMamo sir i have added the details please check

Comment: Where exactly in your code are you using `.toArray()`?

Comment: Sir i have added the code please check

Comment: @AdityaNandardhane brother can you help me with this?? plz check

Comment: @AlexMamo sir have you checked it ? please

Comment: I don't see the problem at a first glance. Have you tried to clone the [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FilterFirestoreResults)?

Comment: @VivekMFauzdar are you fetching all users first time? or you are using pagination please confirm, If you are fetching all users initially then no need to do filter using firebase.

Comment: @AdityaNandardhane brother i am not using pagination at all, all i am just trying to do is filtering the data in recyclerview and adding that data to the recyclerview

Comment: @AlexMamo sir i am trying to clone this but it is also not working in my case i have created the  firestore databse with collection name "product" as shown but while searching nothing appears??

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your last comment.

Comment: sir i tried today to clone your app for filtering data from firestore cheper code but it is not working in my app i am completely confused

Comment: like i have created the firestore databse as mentioned in your code but still it is not showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**CODE FOR THE SEARCHVIEW IN MAINACTIVITY**

```
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        filterData();
        return false;
    }
});

private void filterData() {
        ArrayList < RecyclerviewModel > filteredData = new ArrayList < > ();
        for (RecyclerviewModel obj: userList) {
            if (obj.getName().toString().toLowerCase().contains(keyword.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                filteredData.add(obj);
            }
        }
        recyclerviewAdapter.filterList(filteredData);
    }
```

**In Adaptor class**

```
public void filterList(ArrayList < RecyclerviewModel > filteredData) {
    datalist = filteredData;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```